# Set state like this props in react

Tags: react-redux

Hello i have this code

```
import React from 'react'
import Link  from 'react-router/lib/Link'
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { load } from '../../actions/customerActions'
import List from './list';

import MdAdd from 'react-icons/lib/md/add'

@connect(store => {
    return {
        customers: store.customer.customers
    }
})

export default class Customer extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(load({location:localStorage.getItem('locationb')}));
    }

    render() {
        const { customers } = this.props;
        const tea = customers.customers && customers.customers.map(customer => <List key={customer.profile} customer={customer} />) || [];


        return(
            <div class="container">
                 { customers.customers ?
                    <div class="columns is-multiline mb-100">
                        { tea }
                    </div>
                 : 'Não exitem Clientes'}
                <Link to="/customer/create" class="button is-info btn-rounded" title="Novo"><MdAdd /></Link>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

But i only have access to customers in render passing this props.

How can i pass customer to a state variable in component did mount or else ?

i mean customers const { customers } = this.props; how i make like this.setState({customers: customers}) Having in the beginning this.state(customers: [])

Comment: Is it `customers` you're trying to access?

Comment: You connect `customers`, but you mention you want access to `customer`. Wondering if those are supposed to be the same.

Comment: i mean customers  const { customers } = this.props;
how i make like this.setState({customers: customers})
Having in the beginning this.state(customers: [])

Comment: Shouldn't need to do that since you've connected `customers`. Within `componentDidMount` you can use `this.props.customers`.

Comment: i made this componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(load({location:localStorage.getItem('locationb')}));
console.log(this.props.customers);
 }

and console is empty

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
   console.log(newProps.customers.customers)
this.setState({customers: newProps.customers.customers})

}
```

it works for me
thanks
Carlos Vieira